# How to integrate so many tables (data) from excel into Shiny dashboard?

Tags: excel, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

Although, been using Shiny/Shinydashboard for about 2 years, was not sure if so **many tables along with comment box and pie chart** can be embedded in 1 view which is the requirement.

Was not sure if the following dashboard is too optimistic to build in Shiny dashboard **because there are so many tables to render in 1 view**

Additionally, as shown in the figure below. Data for the dashboard is basically different columns from the same excel file
[image]

Possibly, RHandsOnTable instead of DT might help but not sure.

We cannot change the design from Shiny dashboard to shiny and just use Tabs but is there a way to overcome this challenge ?

Can you please suggest how can we incorporate so many tables in 1 view on Shiny dashboard (not shiny Tabs' please).

Comment: What have you tried (code)?

Comment: Actually, was not even sure if this type of view is possible to render in 1 view. So, asking experts for advice.